# Forcing dependence on a variable update

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say I have some function `f` of variable `x`:

```
x = tf.Variable(1.0)
fx = x*x
```

and an op which updates `x`:

```
new_x = x.assign(2.0)
```

and I want to get the value of `f` resulting from the updated `x`. I had thought that

```
with tf.control_dependencies([new_x,]):
    new_fx = tf.identity(fx)
```

would force `new_fx` to depend on the update `new_x`, but this doesn't seem to be the case:

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# prints 1.0, expected 4.0
print "new fx", sess.run(new_fx)
```

Is there some other way to define the updated value of `fx`?

Obviously I could create a new independent copy by writing something like `new_fx = new_x * new_x` but this blows up the graph size, and also requires access to the definition of `fx`, which I'd prefer to treat as a black box.

**Edit**: to motivate this, here's a sketch of the code I want to write:

```
# Hamiltonian Monte Carlo update, simplified
def hmc_step(x, momentum, logpdf, n_steps=50): 
    # x and momentum are Variables
    # logpdf is a Tensor with potentially complicated dependence on x

    grad = tf.gradients(logpdf, x)[0]

    # initial position        
    new_x = x

    for i in range(n_steps):
        # update position
        new_x = x.assign(new_x + momentum)

        # update momentum using gradient at *current* position
        with tf.control_dependencies([new_x]):
             momentum = momentum + grad # DOESN'T WORK

        # DOES WORK BUT IS UGLY
        # new_logpdf = define_logpdf(new_x)
        # new_grad = tf.gradients(new_logpdf, new_x)[0]
        # momentum = momentum + new_grad

    # (do some stuff to accept/reject the new x)
    # ....

    return new_x
```

It feels really inelegant to define a new copy of logpdf and rederive gradients each time through the loop: it requires access to  define_logpdf() and blows up the graph size by a factor of 50. Is there no better way to do this (barring some equivalent of theano.scan)?

Comment: You could do `sess.run([new_x])` followed by `sess.run([other_stuff])`, that guarantees that `new_x` is evaluated before `other_stuff`

Comment: Right. That's also not ideal since it pushes the update logic into runtime Python code, when I'd rather encapsulate and represent it declaratively inside a TF op, but it sounds like what I want might just not be possible, so that's one of the options I'll consider. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `with tf.control_dependencies([op])` block enforces control dependency on `op` to other ops *created* within with block. In your case, `x*x` is created outside, and the `tf.identity` just gets the old value. Here is what you want :

```
with tf.control_dependencies([new_x,]):
  new_fx = x*x
```

Comment: Why doesn't tf.identity create a new op that depends on the new_x update? Is identity not an "op"? I know I can just define a new copy of the function, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: `tf.identity` is evaluated after `new_x` update because of the control block. But there's no constraint on the input into `tf.identity`, so that can get evaluated before the update

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I updated the post with some more clarification about what I'm looking for. It sounds like the only way to guarantee that a dependency will be reevaluated after an assign is to explicitly redefine that dependency in terms of the newly assigned value?